# Reset variable to sum a score to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This is the ending of a GUI quiz. You can choose what quiz you want to do out of a few topics.

Once you have completed a quiz, it tells you the score from that quiz and then you can go back to the main menu and choose a new subject.

The problem is the score adds on to the last one and doesn't reset back to 0.

I have marked the problem line with **.

```
def EndGame():
    global grade

    if score == 5:
        grade = "A"
    elif score == 4:
        grade = "B"
    elif score == 3:
        grade = "C"
    elif score == 2:
        grade = "D"
    elif score == 1:
        grade = "E"
    elif score == 0:
        grade = "F"

    def ReturnToMenu():
        root12.destroy()
        **score = 0** 
        Start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReturnToMenu` is never actually called (at least in the code you gave us) with `ReturnToMenu()`. Also 
`score` only exists inside the function `ReturnToMenu`. You'd need to do

```
def ReturnToMenu():
    global score
    root12.destroy()
    score = 0
    Start()
```

but that is bad. You shouldn't be using `global` or `nonlocal` unless you really have to (*hint: you don't*). You **need** to completely rethink your design and try and do it without using either of these. You also have far too much code repetition. Try

```
grade = {5: 'A', 4: 'B', 3: 'C', 2: 'D', 1: 'E', 0: 'F'}[score]
```

instead of that verbose `if / elif` block.